# Alter Logging Threshold for Windows Time-Service?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2008-r2, time

The Windows System Log on my machine is getting filled up with these Windows Time-Service messages (Event 50).

[image]

This machine is synced but isn't always accurate to within 128 milliseconds.

[image]

[image]

I'm OK with the log messages, but I'm wondering if there is a way to increase this 128 milliseconds threshold? I.e. if I could change this to 5 seconds, this would be great. Is there any way to do this?

I read [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings#config) and searched around the Windows registry but I don't see anything that can adjust this value.

I also saw [this question](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1093067-time-service-warning) (separate issue, but dealing with same event) which states:

```
The time service detected a time difference of greater than 5000 milliseconds for 900 seconds.
```

Which makes me believe it is possible to adjust this value to 5000 milliseconds, but I don't see anywhere in the GUI, via command line, or via registry that it can be changed.

As requested, here is a screenshot of the entries in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the entries in regedit of key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config`?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, no problem. See above, I edited question to show this information.

Comment: 2008R2 is missing some entries that became available later on. Try the command `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /reliable:no /update` followed by `net stop w32time` and `net start w32time`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, didn't know that about 2008R2. I don't see how that command will help me? These machines are already synced to the domain controllers.

Comment: I was thinking more of the [W32tm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff799054(v=ws.11)) parameter `reliable:no`, but much more interesting is `largephaseoffset:<milliseconds>` if 2008R2 has it.

Comment: @harrymc According to the help (`w32tm /?`), the `reliable` setting `is only meaningful on domain controllers`. `largephaseoffset` is in 2008R2. See screenshot above, it is shown in the registry.

Comment: These are my only ideas.

Comment: Why doesn't this machine keep time?

Comment: @HackSlash I don't know, but its not just this machine. Possibly because it's a VM? We have dozens of machines on our domain with this "problem". I say "problem" in quotes because its not actually a problem, just that they aren't synced to within 128 milliseconds. Would really be nice if I could change this threshold.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 well I would define it as a problem if every other computer in the world can keep tighter timing. This warning is there for a reason. I would recommend not ignoring it. Your question is how to add slop to the time when the solution you need is to keep better time. If it's a VM I recommend using the guest tools to sync the clock with the host. This will keep the VM within the margins where the nettime will work.

Read this: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf

Comment: @HackSlash I thought that it was considered best practice for VM's to time sync to the DC's rather than to their host? Anyway, I agree with you that it needs to keep better time, but I have no idea why that is happening. Must be a bug in Windows Time Service. Just surprising that it doesn't seem to be too good at keeping time, yet it also complains when the time is not within a threshold.

Comment: @HackSlash I also wouldn't be surprised if this is just inferior Windows Time Service in 2008R2. From everything I've read online, newer versions have much better accuracy.

Comment: On January 14, 2020, support for Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 ended. Might be time to update for many reasons, time being only a minor one.